# How to resolve TF10149?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I installed TFS 2015 express locally on my PC.

I am trying to add an existing solution to TFS (VS2013).  I have never administered a TFS sever before.

Currently I am getting this error:

```
TF10149: You cannot create files in the root folder. Create a team project and then add the files under the team project folder
```

What I don't understand is how to resolve this.

In TFS I created my own "Team Project Collection" So when I go into TFS Admin Console I see:

- DefaultCollection

- MyProject

I then launch VS2013 and my mapping are:

Source Control Folder = $/

Local Folder = C:\MyFolder\MySolution

When I click on the ellipsis for the Source Control Folder it shows host\MyProject.

Do I need to create another folder under this TFS project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: You have to create a Team Project to store your project artifacts (work items, builds, source code, etc).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39353331/tfs-confused-by-team-area-project-area-iteration/39353760#39353760) for an explanation of Team Project Collections vs Team Projects.

Comment: Ty.  Now I'll have to figure out how to create a Team Project.